# Issue with Excel DecisionTable to load from newClasspathResource

Tags: excel, drools

There is some issue with the implementation of DecisionTable in Excel file, if i am using newClasspathResource to load the excel file, where as if i use newFileResource with path of the file it works fine with the same file.

The Exception is:

```
Caused by: org.drools.template.parser.DecisionTableParseException: An error occurred opening the workbook. It is possible that the encoding of the document did not match the encoding of the reader.
at org.drools.decisiontable.parser.xls.ExcelParser.parseFile(ExcelParser.java:85)
at org.drools.decisiontable.SpreadsheetCompiler.parseResource(SpreadsheetCompiler.java:126)
at org.drools.decisiontable.SpreadsheetCompiler.getRuleSheetListener(SpreadsheetCompiler.java:185)
at org.drools.decisiontable.SpreadsheetCompiler.compile(SpreadsheetCompiler.java:172)
at org.drools.decisiontable.SpreadsheetCompiler.compile(SpreadsheetCompiler.java:167)
at org.drools.decisiontable.DecisionTableProviderImpl.compileResource(DecisionTableProviderImpl.java:81)
at org.drools.decisiontable.DecisionTableProviderImpl.loadFromResource(DecisionTableProviderImpl.java:44)
at org.drools.compiler.compiler.DecisionTableFactory.loadFromResource(DecisionTableFactory.java:37)
at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.decisionTableToPackageDescr(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:404)
at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.addPackageFromDecisionTable(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:374)
at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.addKnowledgeResource(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:766)
at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:2249)
Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:211)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:168)
at org.drools.decisiontable.parser.xls.ExcelParser.parseFile(ExcelParser.java:83)
... 47 more
```

Comment: You should specify the encoding on both calls.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the reason, why this was a problem. Actually with my gradle builds, i was processing and filtering some resources and realised that xls file being in resources as well, was being processed through it and somehow being changed while in compiled build path.

I skipped this file to pass through those filtering and processing via build and all is good.